# FFMPEG UTF-8 subtitles not properly displayed in mp4 file

Tags: utf-8, ffmpeg

I am trying to add UTF-8 Telugu subtitles to mp4 file using ffmpeg.
The subtitles are not properly getting displayed.

I am using the command,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "subtitles='input.srt:force_style=Fontsize=24' " 
output.mp4
```

I also tried the following,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4  -vf "subtitles='input.srt:force_style=Fontsize=24' " 
-sub_charenc utf-8 output.mp4
```

It did not help.

[image: Improper subtitles in telugu]

[image: Proper subtitles in telugu]

Comment: Set a font explicitly in force_style using `FontName=` and check.

Comment: I tried the following code as per your suggestion and problem remained the same     ffmpeg -i  input.mp4 -vf "subtitles=input.srt:force_style=' FontName=Lohit-Telugu,Fontsize=24' " -sub_charenc utf-8  output.mp4

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. However, embedding the subtitle in `mkv` container seems to work (if subtitle is not displayed automatically, select it from the context menu). `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i sub.srt -c:s srt -map 0 -map 1 video-sub.mkv`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround

1. Convert subtitles file from .srt to .ass.

   `ffmpeg -i input.srt input.ass`

   Note: ASS stands for 'Advanced Substation Alpha'
2. Use 'ass' video filter

   `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "ass=input.ass" output.mp4`
3. If you want to change the font name or size, you can directly edit the .ass file using any text editor.

   Look for `[V4+ Styles]` line ( around line number 7 ) and update the values for the subtitle style attributes mentioned in the line next to it.

   e.g.

   `[V4+ Styles]
   Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, ...
   Style: Default,Mandali,24, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the other user group has helped us to resolve the problem.

By using combination of handbrake and ffmpeg we are able to solve the issue.
We used a mkv file in the process.

```
ffmpeg -I  input_mp4.mp4  -i input_ass.ass  -codec copy -s 720X480 -b:v 494k -b:a 192k temp.mkv 
handbrakecli --subtitle 1 --subtitle-burned -i temp.mkv  --vb 494k -E copy  --width 720 --loose-anamorphic --quality 20  --nlmeans="light" --optimize  -o  output_mp4.mp4
```